# Anyway to customise or hotkey an element in Tailwind?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I just started using Tailwind and I liked it very much over traditional CSS. But I noticed that I have to repeatedly type in certain settings over the course of coding my JSX code.

I am wondering, is there anyway to shorten this task or more efficiently write Tailwind codes?

Currently I have the following - which I found to repeated itself many times: `flex justify-center items-center`. is there a way to hotkey it or define it somewhere as `flex-center = flex justify-center items-center` then I only need to call `flex-center` whenever I need it?

Full example below:

```
<template>
    <div id="footerContainer" class="object-bottom">
        <footer id="container" class="w-full h-12 lg:h-32 grid grid-rows-1 md:grid-cols-4 font-sans">

            <!-- Mobile component -->
            <div class="w-full h-full flex items-center md:hidden">
                <div id="footbar" class="container grid gap-2 grid-cols-5 mb-2">
                    <div class="flex justify-center items-center">Home</div>
                    <div class="flex justify-center items-center">Sell</div>
                    <div class="flex justify-center items-center">post</div>
                    <div class="flex justify-center items-center">chat</div>
                    <div class="flex justify-center items-center"><ChatIcon class="h-6 w-6 text-gray-500" /></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "FooterComponentv2",
};
</script>

<style scoped>
* {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Just create your own class `flex-center` with `display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center`...

Comment: You probably want to use apply if it's for small groups of classes like that https://tailwindcss.com/docs/extracting-components#extracting-component-classes-with-apply